# Create multiple columns on one sheet from 1 column on another with logic

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I am new to VBA and I am struggling trying to make this work. I am in need of a macro that will process each cell\column on `Sheet1` and put the results on `Sheet2`. I'm sure this is pretty easy for those who are more advanced with VB code. It contains many columns..

Anytime we encounter a `—` or an empty cell, we populate the cell with `-999` (see the example on `Sheet2`) on the first column, which contains `"0-2"`. Then we create 2 new columns and populate them with `0` on the first column and `2` on second column (see example on `Sheet2`). If a value is found on only one side, we then populate both sides with the same number.

As each column is being process in Sheet1 and

**Sheet1:**

---

```
A               B
Column1         Column2
Title           Title2
0–2             0–4
3               —
—               5
—               
—               —
10–23           11—29
```

And the results should look like this on Sheet2

**Sheet2**

---

```
A          B            C            D
Column1    Column1      Column2      Column2   
Title-A    Title-B      Title-A      Title-B
0          2            0            4
3          3            -999         -999
-999       -999         5            5
-999       -999         -999        -999
—999       -999         -999        -999
10         23           11           29
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need VBA to do this. It can all be done using the if function.

Column 1 would use something like:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!A2),Sheet1!A2,IF(OR(Sheet1!A2="-",ISBLANK(Sheet1!A2)),-999,LEFT(Sheet1!A2,1)))
```

Column 2 would use something like:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!A2),Sheet1!A2,IF(OR(Sheet1!A2="-",ISBLANK(Sheet1!A2)),-999,RIGHT(Sheet1!A2,1)))
```

3 and 4 would use the same as 1 and 2 just shifted over a column.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, your task is basically multi-part:
1 - Traversing a sheet with smart logic
2 - Splitting
3 - Placing data in new cell

This isn't proofed for working but this should give you the ammunition to accomplish your goal with minor effort.

```
Sub mySub()
  dim i,j,dummy,dummy2, blankCounter
  i=1
  j=1
  blankCounter=0
  '@@@@@@Section1
  do while ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, j)<>""
  do while blankCounter<=5
        if ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, j)=""
          blankCounter=blankCounter+1
        else
        '@@@@@@Section2
       dummy=Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, j),"—")
       for k=0 to Ubound(dummy)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, j+k)=dummy(k)
       next k
        end if
    i=i+1
  loop
                    blankCounter=0
        j=j+1
  loop


end Sub
```

okay, in english. Section one is looking at this workbook ("this" appearing commonly especially in java but this is a more palpable example of such logic). In this workbook look at my first worksheet. In this worksheet lets look at col1,row1. Now we are going to loop down the rows and keep going until they are blank, do the same with the columns. This will basically find the dimensions of your matrix (data).

Okay, so now that we can traverse the workbook we are half way there.

Now you get to know the Split functionality in VBA that also exists in almost every language. Split looks for something in your String and breaks up your string by the argument you supply. Dummy will hold whatever the return values are. The size of dummy is unknown, so we should not hardcode this otherwise it will break when the splitter is not present.

That being said, we now introduce Ubound. Ubound is a functionality that finds the size of your array. Note on this: if Ubound returns 1, this means you have one value. Arrays are auto indexed to 0 so you must note this and not loop from 1 to Ubound, this will give an error and also produce incorrect code.

Okay, good now that we can traverse our array and our workbook now we just need to put these values in the cells desired. var k should be able to do this for you.

As i said i haven't proofed this code, so you are going to need to make sure that this logic functions properly, as i realize now that it does not wrt placing the data in the correct cell, but this will be yours to solve.

Comment: Only problem I see is that the OP said that the data could contain blank cells. Your code will stop once it hits the first blank cell.

Comment: agreed. changed row while to a blank counter while. this should fix that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate your patience as i am really green behind the ears....  I am getting an error with the IF statement if ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, j)=""

Comment: add the word then to the end. Should be if ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, j)="" then